# Rich Text in description of Document Set

Tags: document-set

Is it possible to have rich text (bold, hyperlinks, ...) in the description of a document set?
I tried to change the column type, to add a new one but nothing seems to work.

Update:
Ok I understood that I should not adjust the system content type; but your supposed solution to create a new content type does not work neither. What I did:

1. Created a new content type on site collection level where "Parent Content Type:" is "Document Set"
2. Added a new column to this content type ("my") which is "Multiple lines of text" and has "Rich text (Bold, italics, text alignment, hyperlinks)" selected
3. I added my new content type to a document library
4. When creating a new document set, in the editor window no rich text editing options are available when I select the added field
5. After some research I found the Tool [Sharepoint Manager 2010](http://spm.codeplex.com/) where I had to download the "SharePoint Manager 2010 v2 (Alpha 20110711)" because the other one gave me always an exception on save
6. With that tool I can search for the field (which is dificult because they are not in alphabetical order) and set RichtText to true and RichTextMode to Compatible
7. Then I had to recreate to document library that the changes were took effect
8. Now it is possible to make text bold and add hyperlinks
9. In the Homepage of the document set the descrpition is then rendered as `<div>text<b>lskj</b></div>` all HTML Tags were escaped and are displayed as text

How can I do that this text is rendered correctly?

Comment: Did anyone ever find out a solution to this problem?  I am having the same problem with rich text not working in a column added to a document set.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is possible to have a rich description field in a documetset contenttype, but it's not a good idea to adjust the OOTB contenttype, as Mike also suggested. Create your own documentset contenttype, the OOTB one as parent, and add the desired field.

Comment: This does not work for me; or maybe I am doing something wrong; I can add a new field but no rich text; could you please provide more information about how to achiev this?

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a really bad idea to try and remove or change system fields like this.  I would not recommend trying to make this change.